# Adding Custom Django Model Validation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model with a start and end date range. I want to enforce validation so that no two records have overlapping date ranges. What's the simplest way to implement this so that I don't have to repeat myself writing this logic?

e.g. I don't want to re-implement this logic in a Form *and* a `ModelForm` *and* an admin form *and* the model's overridden `save()`.

As far as I know, Django doesn't make it easy to globally enforce these types of criteria.

Googling hasn't been very helpful, since "model validation" typically refers to validating specific model fields, and not the entire model contents, or relations between fields.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The basic pattern I've found useful is to put all my custom validation in `clean()` and then simply call [`full_clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) (which calls `clean()` and a few other methods) from inside `save()`, e.g.:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # add custom validation here
        super().clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This isn't done by default, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441539/why-doesnt-djangos-model-save-call-full-clean), because it interferes with certain features, but those aren't a problem for my application.

Comment: In Python 3, `super(BaseModel, self)` can be simplified to [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

Comment: relying on a save override is dangerous [if you're using bulk operations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) as save doesn't ever get called

Answer (score 29):

I would override the [`validate_unique`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique) method on the model. To make sure you ignore the current object when validating, you can use the following:

```
from django.db.models import Model, DateTimeField
from django.core.validators import NON_FIELD_ERRORS, ValidationError

class MyModel(Model):
    start_date = DateTimeField()
    end_date = DateTimeField()

    def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).validate_unique(*args, **kwargs)

        qs = self.__class__._default_manager.filter(
            start_date__lt=self.end_date,
            end_date__gt=self.start_date
        )

        if not self._state.adding and self.pk is not None:
            qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.pk)

        if qs.exists():
            raise ValidationError({
                NON_FIELD_ERRORS: ['overlapping date range',],
            })
```

`ModelForm` will automatically call this for you through a `full_clean()`, which you can use manually too.

PPR has a nice discussion of a simple, correct [range overlap condition](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestIfDateRangesOverlap).

Comment: On django 1.3.1 I'm running into a problem raising the ValidationError the way you describe it.  I was able to fix it by passing a {field: (error_msg,)} dict instead of a string error_msg when raising the exception.

Comment: `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError, NON_FIELD_ERRORS`

`raise ValidationError({NON_FIELD_ERRORS: ('overlapping date range',)})`

Comment: Is there any interest in extending `validate_unique` instead of just defining `clean`? Just a question of organizing the code?

Comment: validate_unique implies [in it's method name] that you're validating a unique constraint.  Django's "validating objects" documentation refers to the clean method.  In my opinion, it seems more logical to go with the accepted answer and do your validation there.

Answer (score 16):

I think you should use this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Just define clean() method in your model like this: (example from the docs link)

```py
def clean(self):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    # Don't allow draft entries to have a pub_date.
    if self.status == 'draft' and self.pub_date is not None:
        raise ValidationError('Draft entries may not have a publication date.')
    # Set the pub_date for published items if it hasn't been set already.
    if self.status == 'published' and self.pub_date is None:
        self.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: This is close. I also had to override my model's save(), and call clean() from there.

Comment: But what for? AdminSite (ModelForm) calls clean() automatically. But calling clean() from save() method could produce ValidationError in unexpected moment and it won't be cought as expected.

Comment: Not everything calls clean. This needs to be validated regardless of where it's saved. A broken site page is preferable to corrupt data.

Comment: @Cerin seems anyway not a good idea to call `clean` from `save`. Don't follow Django guidelines at half. If you want this to happen at each `save()`, then forget about `clean` and put the code in the `save` method.

Comment: @lajarre, Duplicating error checking code is a horrible idea. You should always follow DRY.

Comment: @Cerin what you say is right, but I'm not talking about duplicating. Calling `clean` in `save` can happen to validate the object two times (when Django does `full_clean` then `save`, which happens in several different situations). If you're not happy with writing something in `save`, call `full_clean()` before calling `save()` in your code.

Comment: Is using the pre_save receiver function to attach a validation logic a bad idea? We can raise an exception so that save doesn't occur in case of invalid data.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you, 
We can create multiple validators like this use in models.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models

def validate_even(value):
    if value % 2 != 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value)s is not an even number'),
            params={'value': value},
        )

class MyModel(models.Model):
    even_field = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_even])
```

Comment: How to access self in this validator function?

Comment: This field validator does not allow to access other fields, not helpful for the question

Comment: Just to cite the [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#writing-validators). It will be helpful for users to get to the official docs.