# Forms save. Date time discover interval

Tags: python, django

I need to discover interval for `begin_date` and `end_date` fields of my model

```
class Reserved(models.Model):
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

In short when user is saving some data to the database in forms should be validation. Validation should to check is there reservation in interval `begin_date` and `end_date` and give error.

I tried to to this but it does not work :(

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    date_validation = Reserved.objects.filter(room=self.room).exists() and \
                      Reserved.objects.filter(
        begin_date__gte=datetime.date.today(),
        end_date__lte=datetime.date.today()
    )

    if date_validation:
        raise RuntimeError('You can not reserve this room. Interval')
    super(ReserveRoomForm, self).save(commit)
```

For example  the there are reservation in begin date 23-January and end date 29-January but user trying to reserve 25-January

How to realize it?
Thanks)

Comment: have look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7366731/5949840), i think this is similar to your query.

Comment: are you sure that your query is working?. You should use datetime.datetime.now() instead of datetime.date.today() because your fields are datetimefield instead of DateField