# Using a pre_save while specifying update_fields

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have a pre_save defined on MyModel which looks something like this:

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def _mymodel_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  if some_condition():
    instance.somecolumn = 'eggs'
```

i.e. it expects to be able to modify some attribute(s) of a MyModel instance, and of course expects those changes to be persisted during the save() call. I believe this is rather typical use of a pre_save function. This works fine *as long as the save() call does not specify update_fields*.

I am wondering if there is any safe and sensible way to use update_fields in a save() call of a MyModel instance at this point. If I naively call:

```py
myinstance = MyModel.objects.get(id=100)
myinstance.othercolumn = 'spam'
myinstance.save(update_fields=['othercolumn'])
```

The UPDATE statement generated will look like:

```sql
UPDATE "myapp_mymodel" SET "othercolumn" = 'spam' WHERE "myapp_mymodel"."id" = 100
```

missing the intended update of "somecolumn" from the pre_save. I guess this condition can be detected from inside the pre_save by looking at the update_fields which are made available to the pre_save function (as a frozenset), but I can't see any way for a pre_save to force its intended changes to be made when the caller has a more-restrictive set of update_fields, as in the example above. Or is there any workaround?

Comment: The difference is that save can be either used for an update or a INSERT query, so you do have to alter the update_fields, I believe you could check in the pre_save signal if the update_fields is set, if it is then you could change and append? update_fields.append('somecolumn').
Haven't tried it, but you could check if this works.

Comment: @petkostas No, as I mentioned in my summary, update_fields is made available to the pre_save function as a frozenset, i.e. it cannot be changed from there.

Comment: Excellent question. As an alternative to the selected answer, another option is to prevent saving with `update_fields` by raising an exception as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729884/290182

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work-around is:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def _mymodel_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  if some_condition():
    instance.somecolumn = 'eggs'
    instance.save()
```

Note the extra "instance.save()" call.

But you must ensure some_condition() is not True anymore after instance.somecolumn = 'eggs' has been executed.
If not, it would result in a loop of save / pre-save / save / pre-save calls