# Django: All IntegerField in a single instance of a model must be unique to one another

Tags: django, django-models

I am using django-solo to create a model which can have only one instance of it type.
https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo

I have a model like this

```
class ProductPropertiesPriority(SingletonModel):
    product_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(6),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ],
        default=1)
    style = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(6),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ],
        default=2)
    color = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(6),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ],
        default=3)
    series = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(6),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ],
        default=4)
    size = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(6),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ],
        default=5)
    brand = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(6),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ],
    default=6)
```

Here I want to set a priority to each field. I want all IntegerField in a single instance to be unique with each other. The value of one field shouldnot match with any other.

How can i solve this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together) in the `Meta` class of your model.

> Sets of field names that, taken together, must be unique.

```
class ProductPropertiesPriority(SingletonModel):
    ...

    class Meta:
        # set of fields that must be unique together
        unique_together = (('product_type', 'style', 'color', `series`, `size`, 'brand'),)
```

Django will ensure that the tuple of tuple defined in `unique_together` option must be unique when considered together. It will be used in the Django admin and is enforced at the database level.

**EDIT:**

The above method will ensure uniqueness among different instances of the model. To ensure the uniqueness among different fields for a particular model instance, you will need to perform model validation.

**You can do that by overriding the [`.clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method in your model and write your validations there.**

Here, in the [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method, we will get the values of the fields and compare if they are distinct or not. If they are not distinct, then we will raise a validation error. Also, we override the `.save()` in the model and call the [`.full_clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method as this method will call `.clean()` and few other methods also.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class ProductPropertiesPriority(SingletonModel):
    ...

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Write your custom validation to check for unique values here
        """
        my_unique_fields = ['product_type', 'style', 'color', 'series', 'size', 'brand']
        values = []
        for field in my_unique_fields:
            values.append(getattr(self, field))
        if len(values) != len(my_unique_fields):
            raise ValidationError(_('All the values must be distinct.'))
        super(ProductPropertiesPriority, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean() # call the full_clean() method
        super(ProductPropertiesPriority, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**NOTE:**  Django, by default does not call the `full_clean()` method when `save()` is called (Check this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441539/why-doesnt-djangos-model-save-call-full-clean)  for more details). You will have to call this method yourself.

Comment: uniqie_together ensures uniqueness among two or more instance. I am talking about unique number amoung fields in a single instance. For me right now its not working.

Comment: Are you using a form to get the data and save the object?

Comment: No I am not using get and post. Please see this for a moment https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo. We can directly register model to admin.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Seems like i misunderstood your question. I have updated my ans so as to perform model validation before saving. This will check for uniqueness among the fields for a single instance.  Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to override clean() in your model, check the fields in this and raise validation error if two or more of them are same.

I can't say if this is the best way.