# How to restrict two columns not to have the same value using Django?

Tags: python, django, database

I have two integer columns, and want to restrict them not to have the same value within a row. For example,

```
id  |  type1 |  type2 |
------------------------
1   |    1   |    2   |
2   |    1   |    3   |
3   |    3   |    3
```

The first and second rows are okay, but the third one should not exist.
How to add this restriction in Django model?

Comment: disregard my previous link, i think this one is what you are asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281179/adding-extra-constraints-into-fields-in-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing in in the model is ugly/not recommended, you would need something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    type1 = models.IntegerField()
    type2 = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        if self.type1 != self.type2:
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return   # cancel the save - which isn't recommended
```

It is not advised because the user doesnt get any feedback on what went wrong and cancelling the save might result in incorrect behaviours. (signals, redirects, etc.. might fail)

I would advise to do in as a form validation instead if you can.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    type1 = forms.IntegerField()
    type2 = forms.IntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data['type1'] == cleaned_data['type2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Type1 and Type2 need to be different")
```

EDIT 1: Fix indent.

EDIT 2: Added Form Validation example.

EDIT 3: Added more info on why it is not recommended.

EDIT 4: Read wrongly, updated answer.