# make field min value reflect in sql as constraint

Tags: django, django-models

**Model has:**

```
value = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], default=0)
```

this works fine with django admin section, but if you try to reduce value via api, the value can be reduced to negative, so how to i reflect the constrain of min value to mysql database as well? As i dont have database access, so has to do via model only or via django
**api works as:**

 not actual code, looks like

```
StoreCredits.objects.filter(store_id=store_id).update(value= reduce value here)
```

I dont wanna use PositiveIntegerField as its min limit will be 0, suppose i want min limit to be -100 and if someone tries to update record (reduce value) and the value falls below that it should throw djang.db.DataError or some that i can then handle

Comment: What do you mean with *try to reduce value via api*?

Comment: Furthermore you actually should *have* access. The `settings.py` should contain the credentials..

Comment: i have an api when we hit the api it reduces the value field value, and if i keep hitting a negative value starts apperaing in my database

Comment: yes i have those in settings but amn't allowed to interact directly with database as am learning django

Comment: so is there just a way to do so via models only? or shall i do it in database itself

Comment: @AashishGhlawat: you can run a raw query (for example in a migration you construct yourself) that adds a check like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33454114/67579

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem