# Only accept values based on another table ? (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Django)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, postgresql

I'm developing a School/University software and I got stucked in this situation:

**Table Professor**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mr. Ward |
| 2 | Mr. Smith |

**Table Subject**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Math |
| 2 | Physics |
| 3 | English |

**Table ProfessorsSubject**

| p_id | s_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

*(Mr. Ward, Math), (Mr. Ward, Physics) and (Mr. Smith, English)*

**Table StudentClass:**

| id | name | Building |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Tenth Grade | A |
| 11 | Eleventh Grade | A |

**Table A:**

| sclass_id | subj_id | prof_id | foo | bar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 1 | foo1 | bar1 |
| 10 | 2 | 1 | foo2 | bar2 |
| 10 | 3 | NULL | foo3 | bar3 |
| 11 | 1 | 1 | foo4 | bar4 |
| 11 | 2 | 1 | foo5 | bar5 |
| 11 | 3 | 2 | foo6 | bar6 |

- **The pair(*sclass_id, subj_id*) must be UNIQUE.**
- ***prof_id* might be NULL.**

```
CREATE TABLE Professor (
    id   int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Subject (
    id   int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ProfessorsSubject (
    prof_id int,
    subj_id int,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (prof_id, subj_id),
    
    FOREIGN KEY (prof_id) REFERENCES Professor(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (subj_id) REFERENCES Subject(id)
);

CREATE TABLE StudentClass (
    id       int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    
    name     varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    building varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE A (
   sclass_id  int,
   subj_id    int,
   prof_id    int,
   foo        varchar(10),
   bar        varchar(10),
   
   PRIMARY KEY (sclass_id, subj_id),

   FOREIGN KEY (sclass_id) REFERENCES StudentClass (id),
   FOREIGN KEY (subj_id )  REFERENCES ProfessorsSubject (subj_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (prof_id )  REFERENCES ProfessorsSubject (prof_id)
);

/* ==================================================================== */

INSERT INTO Professor(id, name) VALUES (1, "Mr. Ward");
INSERT INTO Professor(id, name) VALUES (2, "Mr. Smith");

INSERT INTO Subject(id, name) VALUES (1, "Math");
INSERT INTO Subject(id, name) VALUES (2, "Physics");
INSERT INTO Subject(id, name) VALUES (3, "English");

INSERT INTO ProfessorsSubject (prof_id, subj_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO ProfessorsSubject (prof_id, subj_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO ProfessorsSubject (prof_id, subj_id) VALUES (2, 3);

INSERT INTO StudentClass(id, name, building) VALUES (10, "Tenth Grade", "A");
INSERT INTO StudentClass(id, name, building) VALUES (11, "Eleventh Grade", "A");

/* ==================================================================== */

INSERT INTO A (sclass_id, subj_id, prof_id, foo, bar) VALUES (10, 1, 1, "foo1", "bar1");
INSERT INTO A (sclass_id, subj_id, prof_id, foo, bar) VALUES (10, 2, 1, "foo2", "bar2");
INSERT INTO A (sclass_id, subj_id, prof_id, foo, bar) VALUES (10, 3, 1, "foo3", "bar3");

/* ==================================================================== */
```

Mr. Ward shouldn't be able to teach English to Tenth Grade, because this combination is not present in table **ProfessorsSubject**.

1. To avoid inconsitences in a database level, how to make sure the pair ***(prof_id, subj_id)*** in **Table A** respects what is in **"SubjectOfProfessor"** table **before** insert?
   1.1) Is it necessary to use Procedures? Triggers ?
   1.2) Is it possible to make this just using fields proprieties and/or constraints ?
2. What if I wanted to do this using Django ORM in a databased level ?
   Reference: [migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE app_event ADD CONSTRAINT chronology CHECK (start_date > end_date);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281179/how-to-add-check-constraints-for-django-model-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combined foreign key in the table `A` as you did with the primary key in the table `ProfessorsSubject`. A corresponding index on the referenced table is required which actually is fulfilled by its primary key already.

```
FOREIGN KEY (subj_id, prof_id)  REFERENCES ProfessorsSubject (subj_id, prof_id)
```