# CHAR field may only have certain values - CONTRAINT

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I make a constraint in a table for a field (CHAR(20)) that it may only accept, for example, "car" or "bike".

```
CREATE TABLE Things (
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
thing CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT thingcheck CHECK (thing = "car" OR thing = "bike")
);
```

If I insert (1, "laptop") it still inserts! Any ideas?

Thanks very much for your time.

--- EDIT ---

As John pointed out, MySQL ignored CHECK clauses. Thanks!

Comment: Why you dont use enum field type? [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)

Comment: MySQL allows but ignores `CHECK` clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
ENUM('car', 'bike')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table that contains a list of the allowed values, and then set up a [`FOREIGN KEY` constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) against it.  But, really, why not just use an [`ENUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html)?

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
CREATE TABLE Things (
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
thing CHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK (thing = 'car' or thing='bike'),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

You should give the strings in single quote !!

Comment: The quotes don't matter (except in [`ANSI_QUOTES` mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)), and [`CHECK` still does nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-not-working).