# SQL, constraint CHECK

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating my first mysql script and want to create a table with column 'type'. it should has only two possible values: 'XYZ' and 'ABC', so I made:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
type varchar(12) NOT NULL,
CHECK (type = 'XYZ' or type = 'ABC');
```

But when i'm testing and inserting values like 234 or 'John' it's working and doesn't return any errors. I think it shouldn't insert value 'John', is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115641/50552) check constraints:

```
The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.
```

So while the `check` statement does not give an error, it is silently ignored.

Comment: Hah. There seems to be a lot of things like that in MySQL. Syntax it lets you write that doesn't actually do anything. I'd prefer it to be noisy by default and say when things aren't going to do anything.

Comment: @theon: you can always upgrade to PostgreSQL ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :D We use both where I work, so I get to complain about them both equally.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `enum` instead:

```
CREATE TABLE test( 
  type ENUM('XYZ', 'ABC')
);
```

See [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2ef2/1). Try changing the insert to 'John' and you will get an error:

Comment: +1 Nice, a bit less flexible than check constraints but fits the OP's problem

Comment: I used ENUM earlier, but I was just interested in whether I can use also CHECK and how i can do that. But also thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems MYSQL doesn't have check....

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25660

http://blog.christosoft.de/2012/08/mysql-check-constraint/

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?136,572271,572603#msg-572603

You may try a trigger.