# Check_constraint on database not working properly

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose: table_name = t1

Check constraint on column c1 is (Y, N, '').

But when I manually inserted any value in c1 column other than above valid values (like A), database won't give any error and committed successfully.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working MySQl doesn't actually support `CHECK` constraints - it just silently parses them.

Comment: Perhaps you can use an `ENUM('Y','N','')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to MySQL Docs<sup>[HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)</sup>:

> The CHECK clause is parsed but **ignored by all storage engines**.

An alternative of this is to create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.", I have changed my check constraint to accept only Y and N.
I also need to change the code, where i declare and initiallize the variable corresponding to this column.

Thanks for all your replies.