# Exclusive-OR constraint

Tags: mysql

During the preparation of my relational model, I'm stuck at the translation of a type constraint {XOR}.

Here's an example:
   I have a file that is equivalent credit by an applicant (a user)
    and it is also validated by a validator (another user) 
    but there is an exclusion constraint the applicant may not be the validator to the same folder.

How I can translate it at my table?

```
Dossier_Equi (num_dosier, # applicant # validator ......)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, note that it is not a *type constraint* (i.e. a constraint between two classifiers) but an *association constraint*. Then, note that *[the xor constraint specifies that objects of a class may participate in, at most, one of the associations at a time](http://stuartgunter.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/opposing-views-on-the-uml-xor-constraint/).*

Constraint:

> The applicant must not be the validator.

The SQL equivalent would be:

```
CHECK (validator IS NULL OR applicant<>validator)
```

(as a table constraint, since it applies to different columns).

However, MySQL does not support SQL check constraints. In another question, there is [a suggerence for using `BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE` triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248038/1297272) for that purpose.