# mysql check constraint where either one of two columns should be null

Tags: mysql, check-constraint

(Sorry if this is a duplicate post, but I can't seem to find an example for this problem)

I have a mysql table with 4 columns like this:

```
SomeTable
=========
ID (int)
name (varchar(255))
column1 (varchar(255))
column2 (double)
```

What I now want to do is to add a constraint so that there is always one column (either column1 or column2) that has a null value. I have tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
    ADD CHECK (
        (column1 IS NOT NULL && column2 IS NULL) || 
        (column2 IS NOT NULL && column1 IS NULL)
    )
```

But it doesnt seem to be working since I still can have cases like this:

```
CASE1:
------
name: bla
column1: null
column2: null

CASE2:
------
name: bla
column1: somevalue
column2: 123
```

How can I get this working so that I get an error when I try case1 and case2?

*(Additionally: if my memory serves me well: the constraint I used can be shortened, but I can't remember how it was done. So I would be happy if someone helped me with that as well!)*

Comment: MySQL does not support check constraints at all. You can define them but they are ignored. Use a trigger instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working

Comment: @Zargor23, the link assumes that I can set the value, but I don't want to set a value, I want to prevent both columns to have a value. Its either column1 has a value or column2. If you try to do otherwise an error should occur!

Comment: It looks like MySQL 8+ has `CHECK` constraints: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I guess this is what you want to do:

```
delimiter $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_check_bi$$

CREATE TRIGGER trg_check_bi BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF(
        (NEW.column1 IS NULL AND NEW.column2 IS NULL) || 
        (NEW.column2 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.column1 IS NOT NULL)
    )
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '44000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint failed';
    END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Basically, this trigger checks values before insert, and throws user defined error.
You should do the same with BEFORE UPDATE trigger.
I hope this helps.

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e617e), just add value for column2 in insert statement (can't save fiddle that fails :))

Comment: where did you get 44000 from?