# MySQL:putting constraint on each character of a Column entry of char(n) type

Tags: mysql, sql, check-constraints

I am making a table PATIENT which looks something like following:

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT
(
PATIENT_ID          integer NOT NULL auto_increment,
PATIENT_CONTROL_NO  char(10) NOT NULL,
MEDICAL_RECORD_NO   char(10) NOT NULL,
PERSON_ID           integer NOT NULL,
GUARANTOR_ID        integer NOT NULL,
GUARANTOR_REL_CODE  char(2) NOT NULL,
TREAT_AUTH_CODE     char(18) NULL,
ADC_CODE            char(2) NULL,
CAPPLAN_AMTMONTH        decimal(11,2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PATIENT_ID,PATIENT_CONTROL_NO,MEDICAL_RECORD_NO),
check(GUARANTOR_REL_CODE in('01','18','19','20','21','39','40','53','G8'))
);
```

Now the thing is I want to add the following Constraint(character-wise) in the column "TREAT_AUTH_CODE" which has 18 characters:

```
CHARACTER_POSITION               CHARACTER_TYPE
   1,2,5,6,9,10                     NUMBERS
   3,4,7,8,11-18                   ALPHABETS
```

Do I have to use the concept of arrays or can it be achieved in some easier way?
If arrays, help with that too....

Thankx.....

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `BEFORE` trigger to enforce the pattern on `TREAT_AUTH_CODE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_PatientAuthCheck BEFORE INSERT ON PATIENT
FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN 
    IF (NEW.TREAT_AUTH_CODE REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{8}') = 0 THEN 
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
     SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid Treatment Code';
    END IF; 
  END;
```

[Sql Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0cd5/1)

Note that [check constraints are not currently enforced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115641/314291) by MySql - you would also need to move the `GUARANTOR_REL_CODE` check into the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp to archieve this:

```
CHECK(TREAT_AUTH_CODE RLIKE '([[:digit:]]{2}[[:alpha:]]{2}){3}[[:alpha:]]{6}')
```

Checkout documentation about regular expressions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html