# How can I implement a dual relationship (Null, Not Null) in MySQL without creating two classes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

If I have a **TABLE** that consists of a **LIST** of attributes of one **TYPE** and another **TABLE** that is also composed by the same **TYPE** of **LIST**, so how can I implements them into MySQL without having to create two **TABLES** of the same **TYPE**?

For example:

[image: Class Diagram]

Like the **EMPLOYEE** table, the **COMPANY** table has a list of **ADDRESSES**.

And I want to implement without having to make one table **ADDRESS** for **COMPANY** and another for **EMPLOYEE**, as in this case:

[image: Class Diagram]

To me the solution seems to be a dual relationship where one of the foreign keys must be null while the other may not be, but I don't even know how to do it.

Comment: what happens when you need to use the same address for more than one employee/company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your underlying hyopthesis is flawed: a one-person `Company`, founded by an `Employee`, could be registered at the founder's personal adress. Therefore an `Employee` may have the same address as a `Company`.

Likewise, two `Employees` may share the same address (a husband and a wife could be coworkers). Therefore I would define the relationship between `adress` and each of the other two entities a regular *many-to-many*, without any further condition.

You might be worried that changing the address of (eg.) a `Company` would wrongly alter the `Employee`'s address. But instead of updating the `Address` entity, treat this case as creating a new `Address` and linking the (eg.) `Company` to this new `Address`.

Now, if you really need to implement the constraint, regardless of the (oh so dull ;) reality, I see no other option but implementing a form of [inheritance as decribed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579462/1446005).

Notice that:

- your initial design actually implements the *Single Table Inheritance* pattern
- your alternative proposal (based on two separate `address` tables) actually implements the *Concrete Table Inheritance* pattern<sup>1</sup>

In your initial design, the constraint can be implemented with a simple `CHECK` constraint<sup>2</sup> on the `address` table, the condition being `company_id IS NULL XOR employee_id IS NULL`

---

<sup>1</sup> Migrating to the *Class Table Inheritance* pattern is "left as an exercise". However this pattern does not help in enforcing this constraint (in fact, this elegant pattern has serious *additional* limitations with enforcing integrity constraints in general). Nevertheless the constraint could still be enforced with a `CHECK` constraint.

<sup>2</sup> MySQL does not enforce `CHECK` constraints, but [a similar effect can be achieved through the use of triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248038/1446005).