# How to combine these 3 things: "check if ID is legitimate from other table", then "Insert" or "Update" by using Just 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Ok, Here is my problem.

I have a rating system that has 2 tables

```
User Table
uID - Name
1   - Tom
2   - Mary

Comment table
cID - uID
1   - 1
2   - 3
3   - 3

Rating Table
uID - cID - rate
1   - 2   - -1
2   - 2   - +1
3   - 1   - +1
```

**Note**:

-In User Table: `uID` is primary key

-in CommentTable: `cID` is primary key & `uID` is foreign key.

-In Rating Table:  (`uID - cID`) is composite primary key. That means **One** user can not rate **twice** on same comment. Rate column has 2 options only `+1` or `-1`.

-Also, 1 User can rate many comments & 1 comment can be rated by many people. **However**, a person can not vote for his own comment. For ex, Tom (`uID=1` created the comment `cID=1` so there should not exist `uID=1 & cID=1` in Rating table cos `uID=1` can't rate his own `cID=1`.

So there should not have any record like this in rating table

```
Rating Table
uID - cID - rate
1   - 1   - +1   //illegal record
```

Requirement, when a user vote any comment the system should check whether the comment was created by that person. If it was then it should reject, otherwise it should insert `uID - cID - rate` into Rating Table.

However, if the insert got uplicate then it should update only. For ex, Tom voted `+1` for a comment2 (it will insert `uID=1 - cID=2 - rate=+1` into Rating table) & then later he voted `-1` for that same comment2 (it will update `uID=1 - cID=2 - rate=-1` in Rating table rather than reject the vote)

Here is what I think

given `uID, cID & rate` parameters

```
insert into Rating (uID, cID, rate) value (?,?,?) on Duplicate key Update rate=values(rate)
```

But how can we check the illegal record?

I prefer to have just 1 query that do these 3 things: "**check if ID is legitimate for insert or update**", if it is then "**Insert**", & if the record already there then "**Update**"?

I am using **MYSQL 5.0**

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you could enforce the FK-PK relation by using InnoDB instead of MyISAM?

Comment: I am using InnnoDB, but u can't enforce the same person to vote for his own comment

Comment: Since [MySQL does not enforce check constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115641/1048425) you would need to use a trigger to check the record is valid before the insert.

Comment: but I don't like trigger. I prefer 1 query that can do all things

Comment: Just (outer) join the table to itself on x = y WHERE y IS NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a procedure to do the insert, and check that the user is not voting on their own comment:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRating (uid INT, cid INT, rate INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT Rating (uID,cID, rate) 
    SELECT uID,cID,rate
    FROM Dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Comment AS c WHERE c.CID = cid AND c.uid = uid)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rate=values(rate);
END
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f1c6/1)**

Be aware though this does not actually maintain the integrity, it just provides a method to stop illegal inserts, it does not stop someone coming along and running:

```
INSERT Rating VALUES (1, 1, 1);
```

This can be more strictly enforced by using a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER RatingBeforeInsert BEFORE INSERT ON Rating
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @found := false;
  SELECT TRUE INTO @found FROM Comment AS c WHERE c.cid = NEW.cid AND c.uid = NEW.uid;

    IF @found THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'Illegal INSERT';
    END IF;
END
```

Then even if someone tries to insert without the procedure the insert will fail. So unless they have the ability to drop the trigger, you will stop illegal inserts.

Comment: "FROM Dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS" what dual table?

Comment: [Dual table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table) is an internal table with a single row in. MySQL states it is not required, however when I try and create the procedure without it I get a syntax error.

Comment: when created trigger it said "Undeclared variable: cID"

Comment: I have tried adding aliases where appropriate, however this worked on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e661b/1), so I don't know why you are getting this error.

Comment: i am using MYSQL5.0 not sure that is the problem. Besides, can i just use the "insert" query in StoreProcedure without creating store procedure?

Comment: Yes, the insert query will work fine while not in a stored procedure.