# How can I input only numeric data in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a

```
CONSTRAINT chk_donate CHECK credit_card_no LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

but with using an insert query to column name 'credit_card_no' with a numeric datatype with letters, there's no error and the value is 0. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you use an integer type for `credit_card_no`?

Comment: Just check it in PHP...

Comment: MySQL doesn't support constraints.  Why are you using a non-numeric type to store numeric data anyway?

Comment: GordonM I was trying to check if the constraints was working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently (MySQL 5.7.x) the CHECK clause is ignored by MySQL, see [manual, CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Comment: Thanks. I read that manual. Its really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your `CHECK` method.The latest versions of mysql uses `CREATE TABLE` method instead of `CHECK`..Changing `CHECK` to `CREATE TABLE`  or you can use `TRIGGER` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)