# How can I fix MySQL Check Constraints

Tags: mysql

First I made a table. The table is created successfully and there was no error.

```
CREATE TABLE registered_customer(
Serial_Number INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Customer_Name VARCHAR(33) UNIQUE,
Mobile_Number INT,
Credit_Card_Number VARCHAR(33) CHECK(Credit_Card_Number LIKE('A[0-9][a-z]' OR 'B[0-9][a-z]')),
City VARCHAR(33) DEFAULT 'Dhaka' CHECK(City IN('Dhaka','Rajshahi','Khulana')),
Date_And_Time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() )
```

Check constraints do not work in MySQL. Am I right or I have a problem in my MySQL configuration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

From the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

So no, CHECK does not work on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.  `CHECK` constraints do not work in MySQL:

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)