# SQL check value in current table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this situation: a set of hotel that has to deal with bookings. Each client can choose a room of the given hotel, from a date `START_DATE` to a date `END_DATE`. 
I want to check in the table `BOOKING` if it's possible to book from the date `START_DATE` to `END_DATE` because there's no other booking in that period.
Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE HOTEL(
    Name varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    City varchar(30)
);

CREATE TABLE ROOM(
    HotelName varchar(30) REFERENCES HOTEL (Name),
    RoomNumber int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY(HotelName , RoomNumber )
);

CREATE TABLE CLIENT(
    ClientCode char(16) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE BOOKING(
    HotelName varchar(30)
    RoomNumber int(11),
    ClientCode char(16) REFERENCES CLIENT(ClientCode ),
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date,
    PRIMARY KEY(HotelName , NumeroStanza, CodiceCliente, StartDate, EndDate),
    FOREIGN KEY (HotelName , RoomNumber ) REFERENCES ROOM(HotelName , RoomNumber ),
    CHECK (????)
);
```

How can I say: CHECK if given `START_DATE` < `END_DATE`, then `START_DATE` not between `A` and `B`, then `END_DATE` not between `A` and `B`, for every interval of date `A` and `B` already in the table?
The dialet is MySql
Many thanks

Comment: Trigger based solution?

Comment: I would suggest switch to postgresql. look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rangetypes.html

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm forced to use MySql

Comment: In MySQL "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working So, you are forced to use something else, like triggers.