# How to predefine column values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to predefine the values I want to be inserted in my table? I mean, for example I have this structure of the table

```
column1 | column2 | column3
        |         |
        |         |
        |         |
```

And I know that my column3 should contain only values for example `YES`, `NO`, and `MAYBE`

is there a way to define that in sql level, or the only way is to do it programatically?

To be more precise, I'm looking for something that will throw a database level exception if I insert a value that does not fall into my predefined range

P.S. I'm using a MySql database

Comment: What SQL database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySql database

Comment: Have you looked into [ENUM and SET Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-enum.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Check Constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

Comment: both are very useful and solve my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use enumeration to set specific values for a column :

```
CREATE TABLE sizes (
    name ENUM('small', 'medium', 'large')
);
```

Comment: After the OP edited his question to make it more specific, this is the clear answer. After creating this, refer to this table from the original using a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create another table where you define YES, NO, MAYBE and refer to it using foreign key ?

Comment: that doesn't ensure that the user will insert some custom value, does it?

Comment: if you do not grant insert right to user,  no user can't.