# SQL - Only allow insert in one of three columns (one MUST be set though)

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

Lets say I have a table with these columns:

```
id | name | foo_id | bar_id | foobar_id
---------------------------------------
```

I want to make a constraint so at least one of the columns "foo_id", "bar_id" or "foobar_id" must be set.. However only one of these three must be set

Is that possible with an SQL constraint?

"name" (and any other possible columns) must be unaffected of the constraint

Comment: Use triggers, is my only advice.

Comment: It only can be checked with a trigger.

Comment: Would be easy with a `CHECK` constraint, but `mysql` doesn't support it.

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14248038/460557

Comment: Couldn't it be solved by a state machine? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your database is not properly designed. When a database isn't designed properly these are the kinds of problems that pop up. Here's how I would approach the design of these relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE Child (
    child_id    INT    NOT NULL,
    child_type  INT    NOT NULL,    -- 1 = Foo, 2 = Bar, 3 = Foobar
    CONSTRAINT PK_Child PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (child_id, child_type),
    CONSTRAINT UI_Child_childid UNIQUE (child_id)
)

CREATE TABLE My_Table (
    id          INT            NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
    child_id    INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_My_Table PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Child_MyTable FOREIGN KEY (child_id, child_type) REFERENCES Child (child_id, child_type)
)

CREATE TABLE Foo (
    child_id        INT            NOT NULL,
    child_type      INT            NOT NULL,    -- Always = 1
    some_foo_column VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Foo PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (child_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Foo_Child FOREIGN KEY (child_id, child_type) REFERENCES Child (child_id, child_type)
)

CREATE TABLE Bar (
    child_id        INT            NOT NULL,
    child_type      INT            NOT NULL,    -- Always = 2
    some_bar_column VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Bar PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (child_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Bar_Child FOREIGN KEY (child_id, child_type) REFERENCES Child (child_id, child_type)
)

CREATE TABLE Foo_Bar (
    child_id        INT            NOT NULL,
    child_type      INT            NOT NULL,    -- Always = 3
    some_foo_bar_column VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Foo_Bar PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (child_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Foo_Bar_Child FOREIGN KEY (child_id, child_type) REFERENCES Child (child_id, child_type)
)
```

Of course, the Child table should be named something meaningful, not just "Child".

This enforces that `My_Table` can only have a single `child_id` and that it has to have at least one - in other words, exactly one.

By including the `child_type` as part of the primary key for the `Child` table and using it as part of the foreign key for all of the sub tables, you can enforce that each ID within the `Child` table only exists once in each sub table.

I primarily use MS SQL Server, so my apologies if some of this syntax isn't quite right for MySQL, but the idea is the important part and all of the pieces are possible in MySQL - it supports PKs, FKs, and unique constraints.

Comment: I guess you're onto something, but I'm still interested to see if there's any answers that actually answer my question. If no-one comes with something better, I'll pick you as the right answer :)