# How can I check if the foreign key object is of a certain type

Tags: mysql, check-constraints

This question is simplified to reduce clutter.

In my database I have 2 tables. 1 table "product" and 1 table "notification".
This product can be of 3 types, defined by an enum ( `ENUM('SERVER', 'SERVICE', 'APPLICATION')` ).

Notification contains a ForeignKey of product, its ID.

When I create a notification I would like to check if the given ForeignKey is of the type 'APPLICATION'. Am I able to perform such a check? If so, is this done by a `CHECK`?

As far as I know, the only thing I could CHECK is an value (e.g. `CHECK(foo > 0)` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This easiest thing to do is a Trigger `Before Insert` and a second one `Before Update`.

You can make a `SELECT` of your foreigner key value to test it in the trigger, and release an error.

Take a look at the 2nd answer of [CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

> Like this :
>
> ```
> DELIMITER $$
> CREATE TRIGGER `test_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Test`
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     IF CHAR_LENGTH( NEW.ID ) < 4 THEN
>         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
>             SET MESSAGE_TEXT := 'check constraint on Test.ID failed';
>     END IF;
> END$$   
> DELIMITER ;
> ```

Comment: For now, this seems a good solution. If no other answer will be posted, this will be my way to go.
But another option, implementing a CHECK or CONSTRAINT in the CREATE TABLE, is no viable option?

Comment: This seems like your best bet imo

Comment: @creulcat as far as I know MySql, there is no other way to do a distant constraint check than with a trigger...

Answer (score 0):

If its an enum, you should be able to check if the value is equal to your desired result.

Join your tables and then use a where clause to filter out the results you dont want. You did not provide the full details of your table so I will give a simple example of what you want to do. My enum is the column "type".

In a simplified form:

```
            SELECT * 
            FROM products 
            WHERE type = 'APPLICATION'
```

Comment: This is indeed possible and is my current solution, but I was wondering if it was possible to add an extra level of safety into the database itself instead of in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? specifically, what is it you want to do?

Comment: A very simple example:

`CREATE TABLE products (
    product_no integer,
    name text,
    price numeric CHECK (price > 0)
);`

In this example, the database makes sure the price is always `> 0`
What I'm trying to achieve is a same sort of check, where the database makes sure the foreign key always is from type `APPLICATION`