# I can't figure out why negative number got inserted in the table while i have used check constraint

Tags: mysql

creating the table named temp in MYSQL database.(using WAMP server application)

```
create table `temp`
(
        number int(255) not null check(number > 0)
)
engine=innodb;
```

inserting into a negative value in  temp table

```
INSERT INTO `temp` VALUES (-1);
```

But the -1 got inserted, i don't why?? is there any problem with the code
[image: Result]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

The **CHECK** clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. 
You better use UNSIGNED, which does not allow inserting any signs, i.e. will only allow positive numbers.

```
create table `temp`
(
        number int(255) unsigned not null 
)
engine=innodb;
```

Comment: using this, if i insert a negative value in the table, '0' is inserted in place of it

Comment: In a strict sql mode, if you try inserting a negative number, you will get an error saying "ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'number' at row 1". However, you will never get a negative number replaced by zero.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support check constraints.

It allows them in table creation only for portability support, but they are ignored in reality.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case of not negative, you could just use the unsigned int type:

```
field INT(10) unsigned not null default '0'
```

Comment: using this, if i insert a negative value in the table, '0' is inserted in place of it and i don't need that,i want to get error

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: to get an error message that value is negative and can't be inserted

Comment: As @rustam Umarov said, it will spit out an error if you are in strict mode.