# distinct value combinations in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have columns that look like this:

```
value1____value2  
value3____value4  
value2____value1  
value5____value6
```

Is there any way to eliminate the combination on the 3rd line, since it's essentially the same as { value1, value2 }?

Comment: Is this from two separate columns? Also, what dbms are you using?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(column1, ', ', column2) FROM tablename;

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working), you can't use [check constraints](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) in MySql, so the only alternative I can think of is to use before update and before insert [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) on your table to prevent this duplication.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach?

```
ALTER TABLE the_table ADD CONSTRAINT my_check
UNIQUE (LEAST(column1, column2), GREATEST(column1, column2))
```