# My Sql Query to check country name is restricted

Tags: mysql

```sql
CREATE TABLE
IF NOT EXISTS countrie (
    Country_id VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    Country_name VARCHAR (40) CHECK (
        Country_name IN ('Italy', 'India', 'China')
    ),
    region_id DECIMAL (10, 2) NOT NULL
);
```

I have written this query where user will not be able to enter country name except 
Italy,India & China.But I am able to enter other country into my table.
Please guide me on this query.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Country_name` `enum` with value `('Italy','India','China')`

Answer (score 0):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See
>   Section 12.1.17, “CREATE TABLE Syntax”. The reason for accepting but
>   ignoring syntax clauses is for compatibility, to make it easier to
>   port code from other SQL servers, and to run applications that create
>   tables with references. See Section 1.8.5, “MySQL Differences from
>   Standard SQL”.

try using trigger . more answers in here :
[CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)