# Small Int Type Length

Tags: mysql

This is my column
[image]

As It's length is specified (smallint(4)), but it does not constrain the range of values
, so how can I constrain that only 4 digit values can be entered in this column

Comment: You could do that in your application code, or your query

Comment: That should do the trick. How does the result differ from what you expected?

Comment: @Mureinik The number in parentheses has no bearing on the range of values which the data type will accept.

Comment: the type limits just the maximum length. if you want to store explicitly 4 digits only, you must do validation on front-end or server side level before any insert into database. the other way is to add leading/trailing zeros (which is useless more or less).

Comment: ...or include the validation within the query itself.

Comment: Thanks I did both  validation (php validation and jquery) but I thought I can do it in mysql too

Comment: How Can I validate in query @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In query" validation can be done like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (year INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT 2016 FROM (SELECT 1) n WHERE 2016 BETWEEN 0 AND 9999;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------+
| year |
+------+
| 2016 |
+------+

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT 20161 FROM (SELECT 1) n WHERE 20161 BETWEEN 0 AND 9999;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------+
| year |
+------+
| 2016 |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html):

> MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type. For example, INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four digits.
>
> The display width does ***not*** constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are displayed in full using more than three digits.

So, you cannot limit only 4 digit values in mysql this way. And MySQL does not supports custom `CHECK` constraints. But you can create trigger like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248038/6209665) and check value inside. Note, that `SIGNAL` works since MySQL 5.5.