# MySQL Create Table 'closing parenthesis'

Tags: mysql

This is my sql query for MySQL:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS java_proj;

CREATE DATABASE java_proj 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

USE java_proj;

CREATE TABLE Konto(
  idKonto SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  login VARCHAR(14) UNIQUE CHECK(LENGTH(login)>4) NOT NULL,
  haslo VARCHAR(14) CHECK(LENGTH(haslo)>4) NOT NULL,
  data_rejestracji DATE DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
  data_urodzenia DATE NOT NULL,
  imie VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  nazwisko VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm getting error out of nowhere, in the line of `login`.
Error: `Syntax error: 'closing parenthesis'`

[image]

Comment: MySQL does not support `check`.

Comment: @juergend: What about writing this as an answer with some reference to the Mysql Doc?

Comment: There is also no `SERIAL` in MySQL. This looks like PostgreSQL syntax: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8e6bd

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments MySQL doesn't support CHECK.

But you also have another problem with that query: the DATE field cannot have NOW() as DEFAULT value, you can change it in DATETIME and set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value

Cleaned up your query should probably look like this

```
CREATE TABLE Konto(
  idKonto SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  login VARCHAR(14) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  haslo VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
  data_rejestracji DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  data_urodzenia DATE NOT NULL,
  imie VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  nazwisko VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

You can read about some workaround to the use instead of CHECK at this link
[CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)