# Constant column value in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL. I'd like to set a column value for a table to be a constant integer. How can I do this?

Comment: What if the value supplied doesn't match with the constant value? Do you want to still insert that record replacing the value given by the constant value?

Comment: No, I want to constrain it to only allow that value so I would want an exception or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Unfortunately MySQL does not support SQL check constraints. You can
>   define them in your DDL query for compatibility reasons but they are
>   just ignored. You can create BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers
>   which either cause an error or set the field to its default value when
>   the requirements of the data are not met.

So here you can find a way around through `MYSQL TRIGGER`.

**Sample Table:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `constantvaluetable`;
CREATE TABLE `constantvaluetable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `constValue` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Trigger:**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_const_check;
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_const_check BEFORE INSERT ON constantvaluetable 
    FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN 
        IF NEW.constValue <> 71 THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text ='Only allowed value is 71';
        END IF; 
  END //
delimiter ;
```

**Test:**

```
INSERT INTO constantvaluetable(constValue) VALUES(71);

INSERT INTO constantvaluetable(constValue) VALUES(66);
```

**Result:**

The first insert statement will succeed.

The second insert statement will fail. And the following error message will be shown:

> [Err] 1644 - Only allowed value is 71

**Note:** Assuming your **CONSTANT** value is `71`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to do this?

Would the following not suffice

```
Select Field1, field2, field3 , 5 as `ConstantField` from myTable
```

Comment: The problem I have is more complex and involves that the rows being constrained as a double foreign key to a reference table. The constant is a reference to the nth table that references a master list.

Comment: still, `JOIN refTable ON (refTable.id = ConstantField)` sould work too. and if some table refer the constant value, then the ON statement is redundant and can be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Although 71's trigger solution is the general purpose approach, since it can be used for more complicated conditions, in your case where you just want to check for a constant value, you can stay closer to database logic and add a foreign key to a table that just contains that one allowed value in it, e.g.

```
create table tbl_checkconst (constraintvalue int primary key);
insert into tbl_checkconst values (71);

alter table yourtable 
add constraint fk_yourtable_constcheck 
foreign key (column1)
references tbl_chechconst (constraintvalue);
```

It will actually add some overhead (since it will need to add an index), but would express your constraint in database logic, and your constant usually has a meaning that is in this way designed into the database model (although it is just 1 value now), and you (and any user with the correct permissions) can easily add more allowed values by adding it to the `tbl_checkconst`-table without modifying your trigger code.

And another reason I added it is that I guess you are really actually looking for a foreign key: In one of your comments you said you are trying to create a "double foreign key to a reference table". If I understand that correctly, you might want to use a composite foreign key, since you are able to combine columns for a `foreign key`:

```
alter table yourtable 
add constraint fk_yourtable_col1col2 
foreign key (column1, column2)
references your_reference_table (refcolumn1, refcolumn2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just set up a `CHECK` constraint in your table when you set it up.  Something like this is all you need in most DBMSs

```
CREATE someTable 
(
someValue int(4) CHECK (someValue = 4) 
)
```

However, with MySQL, CHECK constraints don't behave the same as they do in other DBMSs.  The situation is a little more tricky.  The answer seems to be here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248038/5386243

Comment: Mysql doesn't support `CHECK CONSTRAINT`

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, I just discovered that these are not supported in MySQL. I upvoted anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated my answer to link to the workaround for CHECK in MySQL.