# Mysql check Constraint does not work

Tags: mysql, database, constraints, check-constraints

I'm going to use `mysql` constraints to prevent inserting numbers less than zero. I found this query from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp).

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
CHECK (P_Id>0)
)
```

But when I insert `0` It allows me to do this. Any idea?

Comment: [**See how check constraint is achieved through trigger in mysql**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904425/constant-column-value-in-mysql-table/37904564#37904564)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently MySQL does not support `check` which means it parses your definition but ignores the `check` part.

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

[The docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

To achieve the same you can define a trigger and cancel the update/insert if necessary with a SIGNAL

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid P_Id';
```

**But your actual problem here is that you don't define `P_Id` as auto-increment PRIMARY KEY. Then the DB does all for you.**

Then you don't provide a `P_Id` at all. The DB numbers this column starting from `1`.

<sub>And you actually should not use W3Schools. Their toturials are bad.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> For other storage engines, MySQL Server parses and ignores the FOREIGN
>   KEY and REFERENCES syntax in CREATE TABLE statements. The CHECK clause
>   is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 1.8.2.3,
>   “Foreign Key Differences”.

you can refer this answer [CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working/#answer-14248038)

Answer (score 0):

Option 2, use generated column in combination with a CASE statement and not null constraint. For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
 P_Id int NOT NULL,
 LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 FirstName varchar(255),
 Address varchar(255),
 City varchar(255),
 CHECK_GEN_FIELD int AS (CASE WHEN P_Id>0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) NOT NULL
);
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into Persons (P_Id,LastName) values (10,'test');

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into Persons (P_Id,LastName) values (0,'test');

ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'CHECK_GEN_FIELD' cannot be null