# Foreign key restrictions

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables say, Hotel with Primary Key `Hotel_ID` and Staff with Primary Key `Staff_ID`.
The Hotel table also has another column, `Manager_ID` referencing `Staff_ID` of Staff.
The Staff table references Hotel_ID using its column `H_ID` to indicate which hotel the staff is working at.

I have been trying to figure out if it is possible to restrict allowed values for `Manager_ID` so that only the staff of that same hotel can be made the manager.

I understand that there is a cross-reference here but my understanding is that it shouldn't be a problem. Could someone tell me how this could be incorporated into the create statement for the Hotel table?

Comment: Can you change/edit the table structure to have a third table for the connection between hotels and staff, including the role they have at that hotel?

Comment: @Progman Yes I can

Comment: Can a staff(person) working at multiple hotels?

Comment: No, a staff member can only work at one hotel. And (s)he can become the manager of no other hotel other than the one where (s)he is employed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a multicolumn foreign key to select not just the id of the staff, but also the assigned `hotel_id` inside your `hotel` table. This would result in a weird looking table structure like this:

```
Hotel
 - Id
 - Name
 - Manager_Id
 - Hotel_Id

Staff
 - Id
 - Hotel_Id
 - IsManager
 - Firstname
 - Lastname
```

This is specially looking weird as you have the same id in the `Hotel` table twice. And for that to work correctly, you have to add triggers to verify that the `Id` and `Hotel_Id` value are the same, when the `Hotel_Id` column is used. And since you have some kind of circle references (`Staff` references the `Hotel` table via `Hotel_Id`, `Hotel` references the `Staff` table via `Manager_Id`) you have to run `ALTER TABLE` statements to add the additional columns `Manager_Id` and `Hotel_Id`. The queries might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Hotel
(
    Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Staff
(
    Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Hotel_Id INT NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(30),
    LastName VARCHAR(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (Hotel_Id) REFERENCES Hotel(Id),
    INDEX (Id, Hotel_Id)
);
```

The second index is used for the foreign key in the `Hotel` table:

```
ALTER TABLE Hotel ADD Manager_ID INT NULL;
ALTER TABLE Hotel ADD Hotel_ID INT NULL;
ALTER TABLE Hotel ADD FOREIGN KEY (Manager_ID, Hotel_ID) REFERENCES Staff(Id, Hotel_Id);
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on the value of the `Id` column. If you could, it would be possible to write something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Hotel ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Hotel CHECK (Hotel_ID = Id OR Hotel_Id IS NULL);
```

This would verify that the `Hotel_Id` column, which value come from the `Staff` table, must be the same as the `Id` column. However, you will get the following error message:

> Check constraint 'CHK_Hotel' cannot refer to an auto-increment column.

You have to add a trigger for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries (see questions like [Constant column value in MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904425/constant-column-value-in-mysql-table/37904564#37904564)) to make that check.

The following example queries shows how the foreign keys are working:

```
INSERT INTO Hotel (Name) VALUES ('Some Hotel Name');
SELECT * FROM Hotel;
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+
| Id | Name            | Manager_ID | Hotel_ID |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+
|  1 | Some Hotel Name |       NULL |     NULL |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+

INSERT INTO Staff (Hotel_Id, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe');
SELECT * FROM Staff;
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| Id | Hotel_Id | FirstName | LastName |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 |        1 | John      | Doe      |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+

UPDATE Hotel SET Manager_Id = 1, Hotel_Id = 1 WHERE Id = 1;
SELECT * FROM Hotel;
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+
| Id | Name            | Manager_ID | Hotel_ID |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+
|  1 | Some Hotel Name |          1 |        1 |
+----+-----------------+------------+----------+

UPDATE Hotel SET Manager_Id = 1, Hotel_Id = 2 WHERE Id = 1;
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`Hotel`, CONSTRAINT `Hotel_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Manager_ID`, `Hotel_ID`) REFERENCES `Staff` (`Id`, `Hotel_Id`))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flag or `role` column in the `staff` table to indicate if the person is a manager or has a specific role in the hotel. You won't need the `Manager_Id` column in the `hotel` table anymore. The tables might look like this:

```
Hotel
 - Id
 - Name

Staff
 - Id
 - Hotel_Id
 - IsManager
 - Firstname
 - Lastname
```

When you add a new stuff you can set the `IsManager` flag to indicate that this person is the manager of the hotel, identified by the id in the `Hotel_Id` column.

Comment: But wouldn't this increase redundancy? To see who is the manager we will have to do a join to identify that particular entry where `IsManager` value matches "Yes". I was trying to avoid this.