# How do I add a new column based on a formula?

Tags: mysql

There is a table named "position" in my database.  Following is the create table statement for it:

```
CREATE TABLE Position(  
Position_ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,  
Position_Name VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE NOT NULL,  
Base_salary DECIMAL (10,2),  
Base_billing_hours_per_quarter INT (5) NOT NULL,  
Billing_rate VARCHAR (5)   
);
```

I am supposed to add the following constraint to this table:

A new column called SalaryMultiplier should be specified to the table.
The content of the salary multiplier column should contain the outcome of the following equation:

```
`salarymultiplier = (BaseBillingHoursPerQuarter*BillingRate)/(BaseSalary/4)`
```

The sample data for the columns are given below

```
Position ID = 1 
Position= Drafter 
BaseSalary= $32000    
BaseBillingHoursPerQuater= 260  
BillingRate= $40
```

How do I create the column and populate it with the proper value?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Please include a code example.  Also, what have you tried?  What is happening?  Is there an error?

Comment: I edited the post please check. thankyou for your help

Comment: That looks much better.  Now what have you tried?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: So are you trying to add a constraint that verifies that the data in the salaryMultiplier column matches that formula exactly, or to calculate the value of the salaryMultiplier column whenever a record is saved?

Comment: i have done the create table and insert into statements. now i need to know how to add the new column to the table by doing the above mentioned calculation

Comment: It should calculate the salarymultiplier column automatically whenever a record is saved

Comment: I updated the verbiage of the question to reflect your needs, it's technically not a constraint

Comment: thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [no check constraints in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115641/4233593)

Comment: After clarification, this question isn't about constraints at all, even though that's what was initially stated