# SQL - CONSTRAINT not working, still able to submit values outside constraint

Tags: mysql, check-constraints

**OBJECTIVE**

`CREATE` a `TABLE` for `AccountsReceivables` with associated parameters (e.g `invoice_id`, `customer_id`, etc.). *Ensure that `CONSTRAINTS` are added to `business_unit` and `invoice_terms` to help standardize user input*

**APPROACH/SCHEMA**

*CUSTOMER table*

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 global_risk_partner varchar(32) NOT NULL
);
```

*ACCOUNTSRECEIVABLE table*

```
CREATE TABLE AccountsReceivable
(upload_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 invoice_id INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(upload_date, invoice_id),

 /*Pull in customer_id from another table */
 customer_id INT NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id), 

 /*Add constraints to standardize which business unit is responsible for invoice */
 business_unit varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT chk_business_unit CHECK (business_unit in ('PLP', 'DSI', 'JIMCO', 'PATTON', 'THRO', 'FRANCE', 'SWEDEN', 'UK', 'POLAND', 'GERMANY', 'HOLLAND', 'PINNACLE', 'NBUSA TN', 'NBUSA IL')),

 invoice_value float(2) NOT NULL,
 invoice_date DATE NOT NULL,

 /*Add constraints to standardize payment terms */
 invoice_terms INT NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT chk_invoice_terms CHECK (invoice_terms IN (30, 60, 90, 120)) /* dropdown list of invoice terms */
);
```

*Inserting values into CUSTOMERS and ACCOUNTRECEIVABLE tables*

```
INSERT INTO customers VALUES
(321, 'WALMART');

INSERT INTO AccountsReceivable VALUES
(CURRENT_DATE(), 123, 321, 'LP', 100.50, '2016-01-20', 30); /* This should throw an ERROR since 'LP' isn't a valid business_unit */
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. When I run the schema, I am able to `INSERT` a `business_unit` that is outside of the `CONSTRAINT` (i.e `INSERT...'LP'` where `LP` isn't in the `CONSTRAINT chk_business_unit..`). **How can I ensure that any user inputs are standardized so that the table ONLY includes valid parameters?**

**REFERENCES**

- See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47ba4/1

Comment: My SQL does not support CHECK contraints. Perhaps annoyingly, they will parse, but they are ignored - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working The lists of values you have here seem like pretty good candidates for a separate table, and a foreign key constraint anyway.

Comment: Thank you - typically I search before I post, but in this instance, it looks like I rushed to ask the question before researching.