# time resriction in column

Tags: mysql, datetime

hello I have a datetime column and I would like to put a time restriction on it how would I do this?

For example a range of time from 3:00:00 to 15:00:00 all data that fits this criteria is stored if not throw and error up and stop the entering of data in the column

Comment: How are you inserting data in your table? I mean do you use and client application or you manually insert data to your table using mysql itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you'd have to do this with a trigger on INSERT and UPDATE, so if someone tries to enter a value that doesn't meet your criteria, you raise a SIGNAL.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  my_datetime DATETIME
);

mysql> DELIMITER ;;
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_ins BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NOT TIME(NEW.my_datetime) BETWEEN '03:00:00' AND '15:00:00') THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Time does not fall in the range allowed.'
  END IF;
END;;
mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

I get the error if try to do something I shouldn't:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO MyTable SET my_datetime = '2017-01-13 18:00:00';

ERROR 1644 (45000): time does not fall in the range allowed
```

But it works if I choose a time that's allowed:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO MyTable SET my_datetime = '2017-01-13 11:00:00';

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and some reading. I tested some stuff out on my own server. It doesn't work. Then I found this answer:

[CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

Yep, it accepts a `CHECK` constraint as valid syntax, then completely ignores it.

And while I was testing and writing up, Bill has posted the correct answer for MySQL. Do what he says.

Comment: Yep, it's disappointing that MySQL still doesn't support CHECK constraints. Even more annoying is that it doesn't show a warning when you try to declare such a constraint. It just silently doesn't save the constraint.