# Mysql: Adding a complex constraint on the table

Tags: mysql

I have table say - `T` with columns as `<a,b,c>`. `<A,B>` is the **primary key** of the  table. Now I need to put a constraint on relationship `A->C` such that for an *`a` there can be multiple rows with `c` as `0`, but only one row as `1`.*

I understand that we can put simple constraint in mysql such as -  *don't add column with specific values*([CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)). but I am not able to find a way to put such a complex constraint. Do I need to denormalize the table? or do I need to put a check in the code for the sanity check?.

Comment: Use a trigger to simulate CHECK constraint

Comment: can I have check constraint on the data in table rather than value I am inserting?

Comment: Can you please provide the CREATE/ALTER-statements which you have tried so far?