# Add column in my sql , with values that are not allowed

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

How to add  column,where values in that column are not allowed 
Example ... column age  , values that are not allowed are 1,2,3,6 (other values are allowed)
I tried to use check constraint but mySql ignored it ...

Can you help me with this question or at least send me a material about this question .

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please consider adding more detals

Comment: Learn how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It will help people help you answer your question.

Comment: Write the code in mysql that add column color (varchar(20)) in table boats, default value is 'pink' , values in that column that are not allowed are : 'white','black', 'red'( other values are allowed !! )

ALTER TABLE Boats add column colors varchar(20) DEFAULT 'white' ... ?

check constraint is ignored in mysql!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

Comment: You can store the blacklist in a separate table if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Check constraint won't work in MySql.

Alternatives:

Add two triggers on your table:

- Before Insert
- Before Update

Example Query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkage_bi BEFORE INSERT ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE dummy,baddata INT;
    ->     SET baddata = 0;
    ->     IF NEW.color = 'white' or NEW.color = 'black' or NEW.color = 'red' THEN
    ->         SET baddata = 1;
    ->     END IF;         
    ->     IF baddata = 1 THEN
    ->         SELECT CONCAT('Cannot Insert This Because Color ',NEW.color,' is Invalid')
    ->         INTO dummy FROM information_schema.tables;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END; $$
```

You can similarly create `Before Update` trigger too.

For more info [click here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9668/133886)

Hope it helps!