# Disallow values to a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I want to disallow some values to a field of a table. 
In my example table name is users and field is email. I have added CHECK constraint but I am still able to add these two email addresses to my table.
Storage engine - InnoDB. I don't want to change this.
I have run the following queries.

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD CHECK (email NOT IN ("admin@gmail.com", "developer@gmail.com"));
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_UserEmail CHECK (email NOT IN ("admin@gmail.com", "developer@gmail.com"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

Comment: But this link says change storage engine or create a trigger. @Paul

Comment: It says that it's not possible yet. But MariaDB 10.2.1 will support it - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/constraint/

Comment: I have no option to select mariaDB under PHPMyAdmin storage engine option box.

Comment: BTW: Where did you read about "change storage engine"? MariaDB is not a storage engine. It's a MySQL compatible DBMS (a fork of MySQL).

Comment: MariaDB 10.2.1 support check constraints. It means I need to change or there is any another option(actually what am I looking for)

Comment: Well you will need to write INSERT and UPDATE triggers. Or ckeck the emails against a black list on application side. Even if CHECK were supported, I wouldn't use it in your case, because your blacklist may change/grow and you wouldn't want to change your table definitions every time you need to add an email to the list.

Comment: PhpMyADMIN has exactly nothing to do with it.