# sql: How to avoid same id in table row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE follows2 
(
    follower_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    followee_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    FOREIGN KEY (follower_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (followee_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(follower_id, followee_id)
);
```

How to avoid inserting same follower_id and followee_id in one row?

example:

CORRECT:

```
INSERT INTO follows2 (follower_id, followee_id) VALUES
(1, 2);
```

INCORRECT:

```
INSERT INTO follows2 (follower_id, followee_id) VALUES
(1, 1);
```

Comment: You could add a constraint checking the values are different

Comment: @jarlh CHECK constraint does not work in Mysql

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Oops... I'll remove my suggestion.

Comment: @jarlh https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115641/2469308

Comment: To put this constraint, you could either handle this in application code, OR, write a trigger ON INSERT/UPDATE. But triggers are dangerous when you have lots of concurrent sessions, due to locking issues.

Comment: You can use a trigger to achieve what you want. There's an example here:

http://mysqlserverteam.com/new-and-old-ways-to-emulate-check-constraints-domain/

Comment: "But triggers are dangerous when you have lots of concurrent sessions, due to locking issues." @MadhurBhaiya the locking depens on what you are using in the trigger code https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables-and-triggers.html .. In this context the triggers wil not lock anything.

Comment: @RaymondNijland by locking I mean - deadlock issues. Triggers make debugging very hard also. Many times, we would be looking at application code for hours and hours, figuring out what is causing the value change; forgetting about triggers.

Comment: "Triggers make debugging very hard also. Many times, we would be looking at application code for hours and hours, figuring out what is causing the value change; forgetting about triggers." Yes @MadhurBhaiya code comments to the rescue  `/* this insert also triggers the MySQL database trigger <database.table> trigger */ $db->insert(array(...))` most simple solution and or copy the complete SQL trigger code as code comment in your code so you can directly see what the trigger is "doing"

Comment: @RaymondNijland nice tip. Will ensure this henceforth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `trigger`

```
CREATE TRIGGER follows2valuecheckTrigger 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON follows2
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.follower_id = NEW.followee_id) THEN
      SET msg := 'Error: follower_id and followee_id can not be same.';
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
    END IF;
```

Creating before update as well

```
CREATE TRIGGER follows2valuecheckTriggerOnUpdate
BEFORE UPDATE
ON follows2
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.follower_id = OLD.followee_id OR NEW.followee_id=OLD.follower_id) THEN
      SET msg := 'Error: follower_id and followee_id can not be same.';
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
    END IF;
```

Comment: For MySQL versions between 5.1 and 5.4 you can replace `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` with something like `UPDATE 'Error: follower_id and followee_id can not be same.'` to simulate `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'` and getting a readable error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Error: follower_id and followee_id can not be same.'' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

Your only options are

- Don't add the data you don't want
- Add all the data and filter out the data you don't want in the SELECT statement. (`WHERE follower_id <> followee_id`)
- Use a trigger to check the data before insert. If it's a quick check on two numeric columns it probably won't cause much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If its only in the same row, you just need a CONSTRAINT stating that follower_id <> followee_id

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp

Comment: CHECK constraints are currently non-functional in MYSQL.