# adding constrain to a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone please help me with writing a query to add constraint on **BestFigure** column with "%/%" i.e. it should be 3/10 format.

Please refer the image.

[image: Image Link]

```
create table Player(
Player_No int Identity(1,1) Primary Key, Player_Name Varchar(20) Not null,
Category Varchar(20) check (Category='batsman' or Category='bowler' or Category='Allrounder'),
BestFigure Varchar(10) check (Bestfigure like'%/%'))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working#2115641

Comment: @jarlh you mean to say, use trigger for this?

Comment: Seems like triggers is the way to go.

Comment: What is "3/10" format?

Comment: The above link by @jarth is important, however, if you want the syntax (it won't prevent wrong data) let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution is to store the two figures separately and then combine them:

```
BestFigure_left int,
BestFigure_right int,
BestFigure varchar(10) generated always as (concat(BestFigure_Left, '/', BestFigure_Right))
```

MySQL does not actually enforce check constraints (which is why a trigger is needed).  If it did, you would do:

```
BestFigure Varchar(10) check (Bestfigure regexp '^[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]{1,6}$')
```

Or something like that.  I am unclear what the "3" and "10" mean in your description.