# arrival date and departure constraint with mysql (check constraint)

Tags: php, html, mysql, constraints

I want to implement a web app with php and mysql, to book an hotel 
and I want to create a constraint so the date of departure cannot be before the arrival date here are the method that I've tried without success : 
    `ALTER TABLE reservation WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT check_dates
    CHECK ( DATEARRIVEE < DATEDEPART)`
messe error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT check_dates

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to do the checks back-end side in your php code before inserting records in the table and front-end side with js. 
If the arrival date is > of the departure date you don't have to make a request to your server, so your js must handle this problem. For more security just before execute the query you can add another check.