# Check Query constraint in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am creating table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `work` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `WORKDONE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INSTALLATIONDATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LASTUPDATEDDATE` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `CREATEDBY` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
  `LASTUPDATEDBY` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want add `CHECK` constraint on `WORKDONE` column above such that it takes either of the three values only `('YES','NO','MAYBE')` and does not accept any other values.

Comment: MySQL does not support `check`

Comment: Believe it or not MySQL does not execute `CHECK` it only parses `CHECK` clauses in `CREATE TABLE` statements like @juergend says you need to simulate it with a [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working) (also marked as duplicated)