# how can i put a check constraint to the phone number in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql, constraints, check-constraints

to check the phone number that it should be of the 10 digits , so how can i put the check constraint so that it will be validated

i try using the simple technique but i guess it will check only the digit 10

[image]

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length, technically length would work too since numbers don't use multibyte chars, but it's better to get used to it

Comment: `.. phone INT NOT NULL, CHECK (phone BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 9999999999) ..`

Comment: That seems to be a bad idea. There are many options for the syntax of phone numbers, depending whether it's a mobile number or not, depending on the country etc. They can consist of numbers only, can have characters like +,-,/ or spaces, can have different lengths etc. Better set the logic for such cases in your application rather than as a check constraint.

Comment: @Martheen length function sorted the probelm

Comment: ```LENGTH(-999999999)=10```

Comment: Phone numbers should be treated like an address so it would be better to use a string datatype

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it Possible to Enforce Data Checking in MySQL using Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression)

Comment: and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001726/check-constraint-for-nullable-phone-numbers-column-mysql). though it depends on your mysql version, if its 8+ then `check` constraint will be enforced.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
count(phone int, check(count(phone =10)))
```

try using a VACHAR type so you can use the length function to check if the value consists of 10 characters, as int types allow for negative values, which isn't what you want. You can implement a solution like this:

```
create table d (phone VARCHAR, check(length(phone) = 10))
```

to ensure the phone contains a value of length, 10. If your phone number column does not contain spaces, you could improve validation by using regex to strictly enforce a rule like this to ensure individual row entries contain digits and are not less or more than 10:

```
check(phone REGEXP '^[0-9]{10}$')
```

Comment: As per a comment to the OP, checking just the length of an integer would allow negative numbers, so you should also check the number is positive. As the column is an int, it can't contain spaces. This answer feels slightly inconsistent to me.

Comment: The answer did not include the int because I approached the question from the perspective of it being VARCHAR, as phone numbers are usually stored as strings, hence the regex implementation.

Comment: Then your answer should say that (as otherwise your answer implicitly assumes the same datatype mentioned in the OP; INT) So, please edit your answer to be complete and consistent.